# Struts2 - Set redirection to false

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts2 framework (with annotations) and need help in redirection.

Step 1: The action class extends `ActionSupport`, in execute method add action message. On success of action, location is set to a JSP - `common_popup.jsp`.

Step 2: In JSP check for `hasActionMessages()` and sets a dialog with action messages.

ISSUE: a. On action success due to redirection the action messages set are lost. 
       b. Due to redirection the `common_popup.jsp` is opening up in a new URL.

**Is there a way to set redirection to FALSE ?** Such that I retain the page which submitted request to action class and common_popup.jsp appears on top of same page as a popup dialog.

**ACTION Class:**

```
public class Settings extends ActionSupport {

    @Action(value="settings", 
            results = { @Result (name="success", location="common_popup.jsp"),
                @Result (name="failure", location="${actionUrl}")
    })

    @Override
    public String execute()
    {
        try {

        addActionMessage(" ITS SETTINGS TIME !! ");

        }
        catch (Exception exp )
        {
            addActionError(" Failed to update the data base configuration. Please retry. ");
            this.actionUrl = "main.jsp?settings=true";
            return "failure";
        }


        return "success";
    }

}
```

**JSP Code  - `common_popup.jsp`:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/loader.css">
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
         <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
            <div id="actionMessage" class="ui-dialog" style="display:none" >
                <s:actionerror/>
            </div>
            <script>
                $( "#actionMessage" ).css("display","");
                $( "#actionMessage" ).dialog();
            </script>
        </s:if>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just show the code where do you redirect, I can't see that. Also what is the `FALSE`? Is this an acronym to the known boolean value?

Comment: results = { @Result (name="success", location="common_popup.jsp")     The above redirects the action on success to common_popup.jsp

Answer (score 1):

The result `results = { @Result (name="success", location="common_popup.jsp")` is forwarding a servlet `dispatcher` to the URL built from the result location.

This is also known a default `dispatcher` result type. So, in you code you are not *redirect*, but dispatch or forward the JSP page specified by the `location` attribute.

So, nothing in your code that has shown is redirecting. If it does and you want to save action messages between actions (you should not redirect to the JSP) you can use [`messageStore` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/message-store-interceptor.html).

Find the examples of this interceptor on the linked page or read my answers to find more detailed explanation with examples.

Comment: Thank you, Roman.    The messageStore interceptor surely helped me to store the messages to HTTP Session and retrieve it later.